# If you were to write the LaTeX command `\tfrac` as a Full English phrase, what would that English phrase be?

Tags: documentation, english

I saw someone use `\tfrac` in one of their documents.

What does the letter "***t***" in `\tfrac` stand for?

```latex
\text{young children are often taught }  \tfrac 18  \text{ is  } \tfrac 12 \text{ of } \tfrac 14
```

[image: a screen capture of rendered LaTeX output]

Comment: Why asking twice the same exact question?